# Failure to set and get cookies in Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
app.use(express.cookieSession());
...


res.cookie('username', userName, {  httpOnly: false});
console.log(res.cookie);
```

Logs this text:

```
[Function]
```

Which is not something that I have seen before. I am a little bit confused about how to set and get cookies in express.

Answer (score 2):

`res.cookie` is a function. You are using it to set the cookie in

```
res.cookie('username', userName, {  httpOnly: false});
```

So your console.log is right.

To see the cookie after you set it you'll need to refresh your browser and then outputting `req.cookies` or `req.signedCookies` will show you the contents of the cookie that was set. 
Take a look at the last line of the cookie section in [express guide](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.cookie)

Answer (score 0):

Cookies in Express can be read from from `req.cookies`.

i.e

```
app.get('/foo', function(req, res){
 console.log(req.cookies);
 res.send(200);
});
```

Also, don't forget to include the [cookie parser middleware](http://expressjs.com/api.html#cookieParser).